# Make each input in a form appear one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Im using jquery and want each form text input to appear one by one, the user to enter the data and then the next one to appear. After they have completed the whole form in single question segments, I want the whole form's responses to be submitted.

Is this possible? Or do I have to make the form appear in its entirety to get my desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could definitely do that, however.... why? At what point in the current input should the next one show up? how do you know when they are "done" filling in that input?

Comment: I've attempted to store each response in an array and then struggled to send it off to the backend. I really cant thing of a good implementation. And the user would press enter to go to the next question. I dont want to overwhelm with a series of questions all at once and would rather stagger it.

Comment: you can store all the inputs with name=someName[] after the form is submitted it will be available as array.

Comment: Sounds like a bad user experience to me. You'd need at least a button to say show next question so items don't appear out of thin air.

Comment: Thanks David Ill try that, and you are right Juan, I will add one in addition to being able to use the enter key to move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, everyone is quicker than me, well I'll throw my hand in the pot:

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSFkH/1/) shows you the implementation I came up with. It shows how you basically traverse around the form to get the next container and show it when the enter key (13) is hit.

Dont forget to stopPropagation / preventDefault otherwise you'll end up submitting the form when the enter key is hit.

You can add an exception for when the item is the final element to call $(this).parents("form").submit(); instead of trying to find the next element and show it.

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to work perfectly for my needs. I just need to add that exception and hide the old form elements and it's perfect.

Comment: Is there an implementation you could help me with if I wanted to include a dropdown box?

Comment: @MarkRobbo: If you use the Sizzle(jquery) selector `:input` it'll select any form inputs. Just be careful because it's slower than `input` and will select submit buttons and whatnot as well.

Answer (score 1):

with an anchor triggering new input

```
$(document).on('click','a.more-inputs',function(){
    $lastInput = $(this).prev('input[type="text"]'); //anchor should be next element of present input otherwise use a different selector input.one-more:last-child or so
    if($lastInput.val() && $lastInput){
        $(this).before($lastInput.clone().val(''));//anchor should be where last comment says or else use different code
        }
    else{
        $lastInput.focus();
        }
    return false;
    });
```

with blur event of filled input triggering new input

```
$(document).on('blur','input[type="text"].one-more',function(){
    $lastInput = $(this);
    if($lastInput.val() && $lastInput){
        $(this).after($lastInput.clone().val(''));
        }
    else{
        $lastInput.focus(); //fill this before getting next one
        }
    return false;
    });
```

with enter key press on present input triggering new input

```
$(document).on('keypress','input[type="text"].one-more',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
     $lastInput = $(this);
      if($lastInput.val() && $lastInput){
        $(this).after($lastInput.clone().val(''));
        }
     else{
        $lastInput.focus(); //fill this before getting next one
        }
    }
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: you can store all the inputs with name=someName[] after the form is submitted it will be available as array. by @David Cheung

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having all inputs in the form and simply hiding and showing once the user is done with one.

```
$("#next").click(function() {        
    $("input").hide();
    $("input").eq(++currentIndex).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the entire form, wrapping each form element in a div:

```
<form>
  <div class="control-wrap">
    <label for="a">Field label</label>
    <input type="text" name="a">
  </div>
  <div class="control-wrap">
    <label for="b">Second Field label</label>
    <input type="text" name="b">
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Hide all wrappers but the first, and as the user blurs out of each element, show the next, but only if (1) the next form element is still hidden, and (2) the user typed something into the field.

```
$('.control-wrap').hide().eq(0).show();
$('input').on('blur',function(e){
  var input = $(this);
    if(input.val().length > 0) {
      input.parents('.control-wrap').next('.control-wrap:hidden').show().find('input').focus();
    }            
});
```

This is overly simplistic, and only works for text fields as-is, but hopefully it works as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input:text').keypress(function(e){

                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                     if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                       $(this).next().show();
                       $(this).hide();
                     }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sKK3G/1/) could get you started.